# which one is the better normalization?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, normalization, query-performance

I'm not good at normalization databases and I have scenario that get me confused.

We need a database for a storage software with some usual abilities like:

- storing customers and goods
- storing purchase invoice
- storing sales Invoice
- get us current amount of goods in stock.

well I have 2 options in my mind:

**1. First Solution**

We have 4 tables like this:

**goods:**

```
ID: PK; ->unique id for each of wares
Name  ; ->this is clear enough ;)
```

**customers:**

```
ID: PK;
Name;
```

**invoices:**

```
ID: PK;
ID_Customer: FK;
Date;
```

**invoices_items:**

```
ID_Invoice: FK;
ID_Ware: FK;
Qty: quantity of ware that was bought or sold. for buying number is positive and selling number is negative
```

**2. Second Solution**

We have 3 tables like this:

**goods** and **customers** are like the first

**invoices:**

```
ID: its not PK;
ID_Customer: FK;
ID_goods: FK;
Date;
Qty
```

actually the difference between first one and second is in Invoices.

So my questions is clear:

1. Which one is better?
2. If there is third one that is better than my solutions please advice me.
3. Please tell me some ways that help me improve my power of normalization.

At last sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: Does your invoices table represent a single invoice with multiple items, or multiple invoices?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel actually we have multiple invoices with multiple items.

Comment: In the latter case, what would invoice's Qty contain since it's also still in `invoices_items`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson like the first one. amount of ware that was bought or sold.

Comment: If you have `Qty` in both `invoices` and `invoices_items` then you're duplicating data which is not good normalization.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel I haven't qty in both tables, take a deeper look.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I edited my Q, in Invoice table in second solution ID is not PK, sorry for my wrong.

Comment: If the `ID` in `invoices` is not a primary key then what is it an ID for?

Comment: @WilliamKunkel I missed ID_goods. Edited. Its an id for separating invoices. Actually in second solution I merged Invoices and Invoice_items into 1 table. for example  we have an invoice that some one bought milk and sugar, this invoice in second one stored with 2 records like this: **First Record->** id=1, id_customer=<customerID>, id_goods=<milk> date, qty  **second record->** id=1, id_customer=<customerID>, id_goods=<sugar> date, qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go for the first... with both invoices and invoices_items. It is more normalized. The invoice date and other invoice data you may want to add in the future (number, status, date_delivered or other such stuff) should reside in its own table.

If you opt for the second solution you will have complex maintenance issues. If you want to change the invoice date, you will have to do so on all invoices_items rows. And you will never be sure you just have one single date on all rows. If data can go wrong... it will. To avoid this try to have all the data in the correct table, where it resides logically. Do not repeat it on multiple rows, just to save yourself the creation of one table.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution is better. In your second solution, you're effectively duplicating the date and customer for each item in your invoice, which is both more prone to error (What if the dates are different on items with the same `ID`?) and less storage-efficient.